# ImportError: cannot import name "send_weekdays" from "methods"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал бота вк, и решил оптимизировать основной файл путём выброса методов в отдельный файл и их последующий импорт в основу, начал пробовать с одного и тут же меня встретила ошибка. Все необходимые методу файлы я импротнул, только ошибка при вызове не изменилась.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/arsen/PycharmProjects/Vk_Bot/vk_bot.py", line 8, in <module>
    from methods import send_weekdays
  File "C:\Users\arsen\PycharmProjects\Vk_Bot\methods.py", line 1, in <module>
    from vk_bot import dict_days, write_msg, event
  File "C:\Users\arsen\PycharmProjects\Vk_Bot\vk_bot.py", line 8, in <module>
    from methods import send_weekdays
ImportError: cannot import name 'send_weekdays' from 'methods' (C:\Users\arsen\PycharmProjects\Vk_Bot\methods.py)
```

Код метода:

```
from vk_bot import dict_days, write_msg, event


def send_weekdays(action = 'add'):
    msg_schedule = ""
    for numb, day in dict_days.items():
        msg_schedule += f'{str(numb)}. {day}\n'
    if action == "add":
        write_msg(event.user_id,
                  f"На какой день будет дано дз?\n{msg_schedule}")
    else:
        write_msg(event.user_id,
                  msg_schedule)
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас произошёл рекурсивный `import`.

Например код `vk_bot.py`:

```py
# код
from methods import send_week_days
# код
```

Если вы хотите это исправить, то выполняйте всё, кроме инициализации функций, только если вы запустили `vk_bot.py` не с помощью импортов.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from methods import send_week_days

def dict_days ...
def write_msg ...
def event ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # код
```

Или же вы можете вынести все функции, нужные в `methods`, прямо туда. Тогда вам не нужно будет это импортить:

```py
from vk_bot import dict_days, write_msg, event
```

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю что означает __name__ == "__main__", под этим условием нужно импортировать методы? Тогда зачем второе такое же условие?